# Warning: proc_open(): Unable to create temporary file

Tags: php

I am working on a local server and getting two warnings:

> Warning: proc_open(): Unable to create temporary file. in C:\xampp\htdocs\ *** on line 159

and

> Warning: proc_open(): cannot represent a stream of type TEMP as a File Descriptor in C:\xampp\htdocs\ *** on line 159

My code is:

```
$err_stream = fopen('php://temp','rw');
$stdout = fopen('php://stdout','w');
$process = proc_open(self::PHP_8_0_COMMAND,[
   0 => array("pipe", "r"),
   1 => $stdout,
   2 => $err_stream
], $pipes);
```

I've searched for the solution but I found nothing. I tried to change

```
$err_stream = fopen('php://temp','rw');
```

to

```
$err_stream = fopen('php://memory','rw');
```

but then I'm still getting the second warning.

Comment: Use `sys_get_temp_dir()` to check what the temporary directory is set to, and make sure that path actually exists (and is writable by the user you execute PHP under, although that should usually be less of a problem on a Windows system.)

Comment: The directory is C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp and is writable. It was working well until today and I have no idea what happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found out the answer.

The temporary directory was actually full and I just had to delete most of the files stored there.

I'll try to implement a function deleting old temporary files.